GeoMesa Custom iterator
I am looking to create a custom iterator under GeoMesa’s library in Scala. Will this iterator run at Accumulo’s tablet server level? I want to ensure that the processing of the custom iterator runs at the tserver level.
Tech Stack: Accumulo -> GeoMesa -> GeoTools

Can you say more about what the iterator is meant to do?

For anyone finding this post, there is further discussion on the GeoMesa mailing list: https://www.eclipse.org/lists/geomesa-users/msg01988.html
